# How can I prevent Kendo Drawer from collapsing on click? (Angular - Kendo UI)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, frontend, drawer

I am trying to keep the drawer open instead of going 'mini' when on a desktop-size screen.

I am currently using @HostListener to get window resizes, and values are updated when size changes.

Problem is whenever I click on any drawer item, menu collapses. I am trying to make it collapse only when screen size is over 1200, but it always does.

A solution that might work was to use ev.preventDefault when activating click events, but then I would have to rewrite everything else for managing styles for active items.

Is there any other simler way?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this question is still valid, but if it helps any, there is a property autoCollapse in kendo ui angular for drawer.
It defaults true and whenever you click something it collapses drawer.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/DrawerComponent/#toc-autocollapse

I think you can bind the value for function and handle it manually then.

Comment: Some code would be helpful as an example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method called expandedChange(). use that method an set expenaded = true;

- html

  `<kendo-drawer  #drawerMain [items]="items" mode="push" [mini]="false" [expanded]="true" (expandedChange)="onExpandChange($event)">`
  `
- ts file

  `@ViewChild('drawerMain') drawerMain : any; public onExpandChange(e : any) { this.drawerMain.expanded = true;}`